# SAS 4GL - How to compute weekly stock value differences from discontinous dataset?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of stock prices. Obviously it contains observations only for the days when stock exchanges operate. Additionaly the dataset starts in 2007-01-02.

What I want to obtain is to get the weekly differences in price divided by the price one week ago for year 2007.

I don't know how to do this. Most SAS 4GL procedures do not provide access to other rows then the current one. `retain` won't work since there are 7 previous values to be remembered and accessed in FIFO way. Moreover I cannot use `lag()` since I don't know the distance to the previous value as measured in read values. There are holidays and so on what makes the distance not constant.

How are such values obtained in SAS 4GL?

### edit

[sample data](http://pastebin.com/9btx7p35)

Comment: What if one week ago is a holiday? You could use lag5 which would be 5 business days previous.

Comment: @Reeza to my thinking lag would be good if there were no holidays and only weekends were free. holidays can be pretty irregular and that seems to exclude the lag usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the intnx function with the one week interval. Using SQL you can join the table to itself and use the intnx in the join condition. Assuming your dates are SAS dates this is code that is designed around the sashelp.stocks example.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select a.stock, a.date, b.date as date7, 
    a.price, b.price as price7, 
    a.price-b.price as price_diff
from have as a
left join have as b
on a.stock=b.stock
and a.date=intnx('day', b.date, -7)
order by a.stock, a.date;
quit;
```

Comment: perfect! I just switched to inner join. I was wondering though is there a way to do this with data step that wouldn't be much pain.

Comment: You could create two arrays, one that holds the last 7 dates and the last 7 values and then compare in each line.

Comment: Do you have SAS/ETS licensed? One other way is to fill in the discontinuity with the dates and missing values and then use proc expand.

Comment: Would you so kind to provide some piece of code for the two array solution? No, I don't have SAS/ETS, I'm working on BASE.

Comment: Can you post sample data? And possibly an attempt to stay within SO rules of not being a code generation service.

Comment: I do it as an excercise for myself, so I don't need the code to be generated for me so that I can fulfill any personal obligations, if that is what you meant. I find the sql solution great, I am just curious about the data step solution because I cannot think of any simple one and I think that is pretty basic operation as far as SAS traditional applications are concerned. I'll edit the question to provide some data.